# Smooth fibration on a smooth curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that we have a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ of scheme over $\mathbb C$ such that $Y$ is smooth curve and all fiber are smooth of the same dimension,

> Does this imply that $X$ is smooth? if not, is there any conter example?

Comment: maybe hartshorne III exercise 10.2 could answer your question

Comment: In fact it does not, In my situation, $f$ is not proper!

Comment: Smoothness is a local condition, so the answer is yes if you assume that $X$ is irreducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes over a base field $k$. Suppose that $Y$ is a smooth curve over $k$. Assume that $X$ is integral and that $f$ is dominant. Then $f$ is flat (see Liu's chapter on flatness). In particular, if all fibres of $f$ are smooth, then $f$ is flat and fiberwise smooth. In particular, it follows from the "fiberwise criterion for smoothness" that $f$ is smooth. Since the composition of two morphisms is smooth, it follows that $X$ is smooth over the base.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact the pb is that $X$ is not  necessarly irreducible in my situation,

Comment: Then it might fail. Consider the singular curve X given by $xy =0$ over $\mathbb A^1$ via the map $(x,y)\mapsto x$. This is not flat. All its fibers are smooth though.